# Is this sentence clear? "The fields highlighted in blue are the ones that were verified with supporting documents"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In my company there is a security man who stands at the front door and checks the visitors. Visitors have their names, birthdates and clothes  as fields to be filled in an application form. The security man's job is to look at the visitors' driving license or passport and check their names, birthdates... and update their personal data.

The other employees in the company can see the verified info in the application.

There is a first line in the app to help employees know which fields were verified, "**the fields highlighted in blue are the ones that were verified with supporting documents**"

My question is, how to express the above sentence correctly?. I'm afraid using *with supporting documents* might confuse the employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks OK to me, for most purposes. But it is a bit unusual to think of a field being *verified* (with supporting documents or otherwise). I would probably say that the **content** of the field was **validated** by examining some supporting documents.

A *field* is not really something that can be *verified* (IMO). Its content can be validated. Someone or something can *verify* whether a field is present or whether its content is valid.

But most people would probably say that I'm nitpicking here. The phrase is understandable and acceptable in general, IMO.

If most of your question is about the phrase *with supporting documents* then the answer is that there is nothing wrong with that phrase.  Think of it as one way of providing proof that the field content is valid: by showing some supporting documents. For example, if the field is birth date then a birth certificate might be a supporting document.

Comment: can i say "the fields highlighted in blue represents the features of a visitor that were verified with supporting documents"?

Comment: Sure. But it might be better to refer to *the* ***information about*** *a visitor that was **validated** by supporting documents*. The information does not verify - a person verifies. The information is used by a person when verifying. The information either validates (supports) the content to some degree or it does not.

Comment: I'd say verified/validated _against_ supporting documents, personally.

Answer (score 0):

If it is readability that you are going for, then I would suggest:

> Blue highlights indicates verified information.
>   Documentations are provided for blue highlighted fields.